# Take minimum and maximum of columns in 1x31 cell

Tags: matlab, cell-array, minmax

I have a cell array psdMonth that is 1x31, with each cell a 1x114 int 32 in Matlab. I would like to take the minimum of all of the columns of each cell to get a composite minimum that would be 1x114 int 32. So I would want the minimum of psdMonth{1}(1)......psdMonth{31}(1), and then the minimum of psdMonth{1}(2)....pdMonth{31}(2), etc.

I had tried something like this:

```
 minpsdMonth = min(cat(1,psdMonth{:}))
```

which does create a 1x114 int32, but I'm not sure how to test if it's actually doing what I think it should. Can anyone tell me how I would get the output I want? Or verify that what I am doing is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You might try is make a small, known test set and run it through your current code to verify if what you're doing is correct.

Comment: Simple comments like these help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you did should be correct. More general approach is to use `cellfun`:

```
mi = cellfun(@min,psdMonth);
ma = cellfun(@max,psdMonth);
```

This would work also when the arrays in each cell are not of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct. Another possibility is

```
min(cell2mat(psdMonth.'))
```